# How to build dynamic code logic in Python for a product?

Tags: python

Currently I am working on a product development, I have created an API which receives POST request along with payload. Based on the Payload Information, I need to fetch the information and returns the data back.

How my Payload looks:

```
{
  "Tables": ["TABLE-1"],
  "Cols": {
    "TABLE-1": ["CO1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4"]
  },
  "filter": {
    "COL4": {
      "greater": "110"
    }
  },
    }
  }
}
```

my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import clickhouse_connect
import json
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def GetData():
  if request.method=='POST':
    payload = request.get_json()
    tables = payload['Tables']
    col = payload['filter'][0]
    val = payload['greater']
    query = "SELECT COLUMNS_LIST from {0} WHERE {1}>{2}".format(tables,col,val)
    client = clickhouse_connect.get_client(host='XXXX', username='XXXX', password='XXXX')
    result = client.query_df(query)
    print(type(result))
    df = result.to_json(orient="split")
    return jsonify(df)
  else:
    return "Invalid Request"

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run()
```

My code is very hard coded, I wanted to know how I can make my code dynamic, so that I can take any payload request dynamically as per the below scenarios and create a query or do etl in python and return the result.

Scenarios:

1. Payload can contain one or more Tables or columns
2. It may or may not contain filter or any functionalities.

I am seeking suggestions for code template or how can I design my code so that in future I can add more layers to it.

Comment: There is no "code template" for this – but you'd just write something to turn that JSON payload to an SQL query. You might want to look at a query builder library such as https://github.com/kayak/pypika to make your job easier.